# AngularJS - Toggle object value boolean on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm building a ToDo application to learn Angular JS.

In my app I have an array called `toDoList`, that I push objects into based on some inputs from the user, this is done elsewhere in a modal.

That item then displays on the UI.

I have a button, which I want to use to show the task has been completed. In the objects one of the properties is `done`, this is initially set to `false`.

When the button is clicked, I want the value to toggle between `false` and `true` for that specific  object in the `toDoList` array. So not to set all of the objects done property only the specific object on the generated `ng-repeat` element.

The button I'm referring to is the `itemComplete` button.

I have tried using `booleanVal` toggle on the `ng-click`, but this is throwing errors for me in the console.

Index.html

```
<div class="row newItem" ng-show="toDoList.length > 0"
     ng-repeat="item in toDoList">
    <div class="col-2">
        <button class="itemComplete btn"
                ng-click="item.done.booleanVal = !item.done.booleanVal">
          <i class="far fa-check-circle fa-2x"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <h4>{{item.project}}</h4>
        <p>{{item.task}}.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <button class="btn deleteItem"
                ng-click="deleteItem($index); getTaskCount()">
          <i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

App.module.js

```
$scope.toDoList = [];

$scope.addNewToDoTask = function () {
    $scope.toDoList.push({
        project: $scope.projectInput,
        task: $scope.taskInput,
        done: false
    });
    $scope.projectInput = "";
    $scope.taskInput = "";
};
```

Comment: One of the keys to debugging a problem it to examine error messages and their stack traces. We can't help with an error message if the question does not include any error messages. **Double-check that your example reproduces the problem!** If you inadvertently fixed the problem while composing the example but didn't test it again, you'd want to know that before asking someone else to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `item.done.booleanVal` with `item.done` in `ng-click` expression.

Answer (score 0):

The Error Message:

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'booleanVal' on boolean 'false'
>
> ```
> at fn (eval at compile (VM335 angular.js:16421), <anonymous>:4:461)
> at callback (VM335 angular.js:28954)
> at ChildScope.$eval (VM335 angular.js:19396)
> at ChildScope.$apply (VM335 angular.js:19495)
> at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (VM335 angular.js:28958)
> at defaultHandlerWrapper (VM335 angular.js:3826)
> at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (VM335 angular.js:3814)
> ```

Pretty obvious:

```
<button class="itemComplete btn"
        ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶"̶i̶t̶e̶m̶.̶d̶o̶n̶e̶.̶b̶o̶o̶l̶e̶a̶n̶V̶a̶l̶ ̶=̶ ̶!̶i̶t̶e̶m̶.̶d̶o̶n̶e̶.̶b̶o̶o̶l̶e̶a̶n̶V̶a̶l̶"̶>̶
        ng-click="item.done = !item.done">
  <i class="far fa-check-circle fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

Boolean values are primitives. They don't have properties.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/c45VnYdLsJRv22zuuFoi?p=preview)